# After installing anaconda on ubuntu 16.04 "python3" command doesn't found

Tags: python, anaconda

I've installed Anaconda on ubuntu 16.04. After installing it I can not open python interactive shell by using command "python3". what should I do?

Comment: does `python3` binary exist in your system path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set the right `path`

```
export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: it's working but every time I opened my terminal I have to set this path. What is the permanent solution?